# DATE queries using BETWEEN on oracle view

Tags: oracle

i have a problem with a date parameter query using 'between' operator in oracle view, when i do this query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM MY_VIEW 
WHERE STATUS = 'Active' 
AND CHECKER_DATE BETWEEN to_date(sysdate - 1, 'DD-MON-YY') AND to_date(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YY');
```

it does not give me the records (actualy i have any record on that date).

I try using 'in' operator, but still not give me the records.

Please throw some information for this.

*checker_date defined as date

Comment: What is your `MY_VIEW` and your original database tables? Everyone cannot answer if don't know about it.

Comment: **NEVER**, ever call `to_date()` on a value that is already a date. That will first convert the `date` value to a `varchar` just to convert that `varchar` back to a `date` which it was to begin with.

Comment: You probably need `trunc(sysdate-1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first error is to call to_date() on a value that is already a DATE. `to_date()` expects a VARCHAR value, so `sysdate` will be first converted to VARCHAR and will then immediately be converted back to a DATE value which it was to begin with.

You probably want

```
AND CHECKER_DATE BETWEEN trunc(sysdate) - 1 AND trunc(sysdate)
```

Most probably this will still not give you want you want as that would **not** include rows from "today". `trunc(sysdate)` means "today at midnight" and any row that was created today after midnight will not be included. With date/time values (and Oracle's DATE type does contain a time, despite the name) it's better to not use BETWEEN, but explicit range operators instead:

```
AND CHECKER_DATE >= trunc(sysdate) - 1 
AND CHECKER_DATE < trunc(sysdate) + 1
```

`trunc(sysdate) + 1` is tomorrow at midnight, so any value that is (strictly) smaller than that is "today".

---

All the above assumes that `CHECKER_DATE` is defined as `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MY_VIEW 
WHERE STATUS = 'Active' 
AND CHECKER_DATE BETWEEN trunc(sysdate - 1) AND trunc(sysdate);
```

Oracle advises against using to_date for date. Also trunc is here because Trunc removes the time component.

Answer (score 0):

may be records are not 'Active' or 'Active' a not-existing value in one of the reference tables if any and trunc(sysdate -1) and trunc(sysdate) would help